# Removing a field from the new content form

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have created a content type which consists of a title a .zip file and a screenshot using Drupal 7's site builder.

When a user adds an instance of this content type I would like for them to only have exposed fields for the .zip file and the title.  I have a custom module that unzips the .zip file and does some analysis and I would like to extract the screenshot at this time.

Is there anyway that I can have the new content form of my content type not show the screenshot field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three good options:

- [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) has a feature to hide fields from the form
- You can use hook_form_node_form_alter to remove the field

**Edit**: per Clive's suggestion, set ['#access'] = FALSE instead of unset($form['field_zip_file'])

Create a new module, (create MY_MODULE.info, MY_MODULE.module), and add this to MY_MODULE.module:

```
<?php

  function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form['#node']->type == 'my_content_type') {
      if ($form['nid']['#value'] == '') {
        $form['field_zip_file']['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
```

- Use CSS to make it disappear:

Add this to your theme's CSS file:

```
body.page-node-add #edit-field-zip-file {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Sweet I tried your second suggestion and it worked like a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: Removing the element from the form array isn't the best idea (it may well cause PHP warnings in validate/submit handlers). The best way would be to use `$form['field_zip_file']['#access'] = FALSE;`.